# Mongoose populate()

Tags: express, mongoose-populate, mongoose-models

referring to Mongoose url populate example given at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#checking-populated , there seems to be a two way relationship between both Schema. What if I only have 1 way relationship for example ( using same schema example, But Person schema **does not** Story ref )

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

How can I return a GET Story output that looks like the following :

```
{
  author :{
    name: "Bla bla bla",
    age: 30
  }
  title : "ABC Story"
}
```

I am always getting this at the moment :

```
{
  author :34235245453
  title : "ABC Story"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing populated() function and populate() function.

To be able to retrieve the author info of a story, we need to use populate like this:

```js
router.get("/stories/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Story.findById(req.params.id).populate("author");
  res.send(result);
});
```

Let's say we have this person:

```
{
    "_id": "5e3c63ba3a178830dc497a00",
    "name": "Name1",
    "age": 33,
    "__v": 0
}
```

And this story by user:

```
{
    "_id": "5e3c63e93a178830dc497a02",
    "author": "5e3c63ba3a178830dc497a00",
    "title": "Story1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The result will be like this when we send a get request to our route ( `http://.../stories/5e3c63f33a178830dc497a02`)

```
{
    "_id": "5e3c63e93a178830dc497a02",
    "author": {
        "_id": "5e3c63ba3a178830dc497a00",
        "name": "Name1",
        "age": 33,
        "__v": 0
    },
    "title": "Story1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

To get all stories with author info, we can use find() method like this:

```js
router.get("/stories", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Story.find().populate("author");
  res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: Hi @SuleymanSah, if i want a get all stories , I can use .find().populate(‘author’)?  I am doing this now but i’m not getting the author information when i send a get all request. The output i’m getting is the 1 i posted

Comment: @BC2 yes you can get all stories and  author info  with code in your comment. Can you show me the full code you used?

Comment: i'll try to edit the question to include my example.

Comment: I've managed to get my desired output by using Richard Job's example. Thanks for helping me :D

Comment: @BC2 my answer should work, his answer is similar to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is a good practise, but you can achieve this as follows

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //modified by just defining the type
  title: String
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

when populating,

```
SOMETHING.find()
.populate({
   'path':'author',
   'model':'Person'
});
```

Comment: THanks Richard. It works. Although I did not include the ' for model. 

`await Story.find().populate({
      'path':'author',
      'model':Person
    });`

i got "Schema hasn't been registered for model" if i use the ' for the value. All is good now .